# Other than the Online Documentation is there any way to find out the minimum api version for a given class, method etc in Android

Tags: java, android, dex, .class-file

I am happy to write a extractor for .class files or dex files. I just need to find some machine readable source for this data other than scraping the docs. Currently my options includes parsing every .class file for each api version and comparing them, or parsing the docs.

Neither seem that fun, so any idea would be gratefully received.

Comment: Isn't this normally listed in the application manifest?

Comment: @Antimony: No I mean the minimum version per method. As in which android api version was it first available in

Answer (score 0):

The android.jar for each api level from the Android sdk only contains the public apis for that api level. You could inspect the android.jar for each level and find the first api level a given api is present in.

There is also the "current.xml" file in AOSP for older platforms, and "current.txt" for newer platforms, which defines the public api for the associated api level. So you could also do something similar to my above suggestion by inspecting the current.xml/current.txt files for all apis.

e.g.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread/api/current.xml
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/api/current.txt